# How to specify more than one condition using Eager-Load in Laravel 4?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-4.2

In Laravel documentation [Eager Load Constraits](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#eager-loading). This is the way to eager load a relation with specific condition:

```
$users = User::with(array('posts' => function($query){
    $query->where('title', 'like', '%first%');

}))->get();
```

and This works fine, but what am looking for is something like this:

```
$users = User::with(array('posts' => function($query){
    $query->where('title', 'like', '%first%')
    ->orWhere('title', 'like', '%second%');
}))->get();
```

So i would get a result of this or that, tried to look for this for a while but couldn't find an answer!

I have implemented something that works but would love to improve it!
Basically what i did was i created a second variable which will apply the second statement. Is there a better way of doing this ?!

Comment: Doesn't your second code block work? What's the error?

Comment: @Paras It Doesn't throw an error, but will apply the first condition only. What i have done is working so far, so i made a second function which specify the relation with a table n then i call this function n i pass the second condition. Something like this:

$users = User::with(array('posts' => function($query){
    $query->where('title', 'like', '%first%');
}))->with(array('posts2' => function($query) {
    $query->where('title','like', '%second%');
}))->get();